# How to setup playing system audio into teamspeak

Tags: linux, audio, teamspeak

I have Fedora distro (21) running in a VirtualBox VM

I want to be able to take the system's output audio and feed it into the teamspeak input (capture)

The reason for this is for a game I play I want to use website soundboards to inject 'game sounds' into teamspeak.

Having the ambient sounds connected as a separate user allows others to control volume etc.

The VM has the audio host device set to: Null audio driver. Because I don't want the sound played on my host machine where I will also be using teamspeak.

I tried add snd_aloop - but didn't know what I was doing with it and setting the teamspeak capture to the loopback seemed to do nothing

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment rather then an answer (but i cant post comments yet :( ), but have you looked into `alsa` and `pulseaudio`

from its wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio)

> PulseAudio is a sound server, a background process **accepting sound input** from one or more sources (processes or capture devices) and **redirecting it to one or more sinks** (sound cards, remote network PulseAudio servers, or other processes)

So in theory you can redirect `alsa` to `pulseaudio` and use `pulseaudio` to redirect the audio where you want (to teamspeak). I wouldn't know how to do this, but it sounds possible

EDIT:

Start with `pavucontrol`. This is a nice GUI for `pulseaudio` that may help you redirect audio somewhere else